# Function that checks Java program arguments

Tags: java, arguments

I'm trying to re-write this code in a cleaner way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(checkArgs(args) < 0) return; 
    return;
}

private static int checkArgs(String[] args) {       
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: No Args");
        return -1;
    }
    try{ //If it's a number
        int myNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("My number is: " + myNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {//If it's a String
        try{
            String[] myStr = args ;
            System.out.print("My String is ");
            for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
                myStr[i] = args[i];
                System.out.print(myStr[i]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            return 0;
        }
        catch(Exception err){
            System.out.println("Error");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code checks the program args and tell the user if it's a String or just a number.

Any ideas on how to re-write this code without using try-catch?

Comment: There seems to be a method inside a method here...

Comment: Indeed - this code doesn't compile at all.

Comment: It's inside the method int checkArgs(String Args[])

Comment: That method itself doesn't compile either, the final `return 0;` is unreachable.

Comment: Please give code that actually compiles and runs. Preferably following conventions such as naming variables with a lower case initial letter. Hint: you should also check that your array has any elements before you try to access `args[0]` or others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't really need the second `try...catch`. This code:

```
        String[] myStr = args ;
        System.out.print("My String is ");
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            myStr[i] = args[i];
            System.out.print(myStr[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        return 0;
```

Is not throwing any checked exception and is not very likely to ever throw a runtime exception.

Second, this code also has parts that are simply not needed - the `myStr` array - you assign the `args` array to it, and then you assign each element individually to it. And it's a local variable so it's going to go away as soon as you `return` anyway.

So:

```
        System.out.print("My String is ");
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        return 0;
```

would do the same thing and is not going to throw exceptions.

Now, as for checking the integer - I think just using it like this and catching the exception is good enough. Just catch `NumberFormatException` instead of `Exception`. It's never a good idea to do a catch-all.

But if you insist on a method without try-catch, you could do something like this:

```
private static boolean checkInt(String str) {
    if ( ! str.matches("-?0*[0-9]{1,10}")) {
        return false;
    }
    long l = Long.valueOf(str);
    if ( l > Integer.MAX_VALUE || l < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("My number is: " + myNumber);
    return true;
}
```

This first checks that you have no more than 10 digits with or without a minus sign (and any number of preceding zeros). If so, then it can be safely converted to a `long`, without exception checking. You can then check if the resulting `long` is in the range of an integer. It's a workaround that requires no try and catch, but I don't think it's better than the try-catch method.

So, with try-catch, you would have:

```
private static int checkArgs1(String[] args) {
    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: No Args");
        return -1;
    }
    try { // If it's a number
        int myNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("My number is: " + myNumber);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {// If it's a String
        String[] myStr = args;
        System.out.print("My String is ");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            myStr[i] = args[i];
            System.out.print(myStr[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And without it, using my `checkInt()` method:

```
private static int checkArgs2(String[] args) {
    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: No Args");
        return -1;
    }
    if ( ! checkInt(args[0])) {
        // If it's a String
        String[] myStr = args;
        System.out.print("My String is ");
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            myStr[i] = args[i];
            System.out.print(myStr[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not really sure how useful your check is, though. Usually, argument checking is done in preparation for doing something with the args, and you don't save the information about whether it was a number or a string anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments your code has compilation issues. As far as logic is concerned, to find out if an input string contains only digits or not, you can use regex as shown below.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^-?[0-9]+$");

if(p.matcher(arg[0]).matches()) {
    System.out.println("It's a number!!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a number.");
}
```

In this case you don't have to use `try/catch` block.

Comment: That alone won't suffice. `Integer.parseInt` also throws an exception, if the value is out of `int` range, e.g. for `Integer.parseInt("9999999999")` , see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-

Answer (score -1):

Try like this...

```
public class CheckArgs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args != null && args.length != 0) {
            for (String arg : args) {
                System.out.println(String.format("<----- %s ----->", arg));
                System.out.println(String.format("is number %s", checkIfNumber(arg)));
                System.out.println(String.format("is string %s", checkIfString(arg)));
                System.out.println(String.format("<-------------->", arg));
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkIfString(Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceof String) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkIfNumber(Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceof Integer) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```